# Why is the ParseFilePipe validation not working as intended in my nestjs api route?

Tags: validation, nestjs, multer, interceptor

**First Problem (Max File Size)**
I've set the max file size 2MB but I still get error even when I uploaded an image that is few kbs in size. The code:

```
  @Patch()
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard)
  @UseInterceptors(
    FileFieldsInterceptor([
      { name: 'avatar', maxCount: 1 },
      { name: 'cover', maxCount: 1 },
    ])
  )
  async update(
    @Request() req,
    @Body(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true, whitelist: true }))
    updateProfileDto: UpdateProfileDto,
    @UploadedFiles(
      new ParseFilePipe({
        fileIsRequired: false,
        validators: [
          new MaxFileSizeValidator({
            maxSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024,
            message: 'File is too large. Max size is 2MB',
          }),
        ],
        errorHttpStatusCode: HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
      })
    )
    files
  ) {
    console.log('files', files);
  }
```

PATCH Request Using Postman.
URL: http://localhost:5984/api/profile
Attached image in form-data tab.

The Response I get:

```
{
    "path": "/api/profile",
    "statusCode": 422,
    "message": [
        "File is too large. Max size is 2MB"
    ],
    "success": false
}
```

**Second Problem (File Type Validation)**

When uploading a .png image.

```
{
    "path": "/api/profile",
    "statusCode": 422,
    "message": [
        "Validation failed (expected type is .(png|jpeg|jpg))"
    ],
    "success": false
}
```

I tried using `ParseFilePipeBuilder` instead of ParseFilePipe, but no difference.
For file type validation, I tried setting the fileType as `image/png`, `png`, `.png` etc.
Please let me know if I missed to attach any other information in this post.